# Zk onClick event fail

Tags: events, onclick, include, zk

I explain a bit the situation, I have a zul that includes 2 differents zuls.
One of this zuls have a listbox with this structure:

```
<listbox id="list" model="@{layout$composer.listData}">
    <listhead>
        <listheader label="">
            <grid>
                <columns>
                    ....
                </columns>
            </grid>
        </listheader>
    </listhead>

    <template name="model">
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="">
                <groupbox mold="3d" open="false">
                    <caption>
                        <span />
                        <grid>
                            <rows>
                                ... (list data)
                            </rows>
                        </grid>
                    </caption>
                    <window border="normal" width="1010px">
                        <vbox>
                            <hbox>
                                ... (general data)
                            </hbox>
                            <zk if="${each.var == 'DATA'}" >
                                ... (specific data)
                            </zk>
                            <hbox>
                                <button forward="onClick=list.onSaveClick(${each})" />
                                <button forward="onClick=list.onDelClick(${each})" />
                            </hbox>
                        </vbox>
                    </window>

                    <separator />
                    <separator />
                </groupbox>

            </listcell>
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
```

In my controller i tried to catch this event like:

```
@Listen("onSaveClick=#includeTab #list")
public void onSaveClick(ForwardEvent ev) { ... }
```

and this doesn't work, for now I move the buttons to the rows in the "list data", there i can get the events like:

```
@Listen("onSaveClick=#includeTab #list")
public void onSaveClick(ForwardEvent ev) { ... }
```

I need the buttons where they are at the begining so I need to catch the onClick event, but I'm not abble to do.

Is possible to catch this event? 
If is possible, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can catch the event using a  component instead the  component. Still don't know why this works and the other doesn't.